Rocker container: change HOME variable
Currently I am using a Rocker container for using Rstudio, with a mounted storage volume.
When I start the container, the HOME directory conaining the profile settings and for example git credentials is located on the container. When restarting the container, all saved settings get lost. So I would like to change the HOME folder to a user specific folder on the mounted storage volume (/aci/scripts/R.generiek/User.settings/$USER), such that all save user settings get loaded again.
I tried to copy an .Renviron containing:
HOME='/aci/scripts/R.generiek/User.settings/$USER'
However the container cannot start properly after adding this HOME variable.
Does anyone know how to change the HOME directory of a Rocker container?
When I change the .Renviron file manually, the HOME folder is correct after starting a new R session.
My Rocker script is:
FROM rocker/tidyverse:latest
 
#Set argument
ARG USER
 
## copy files
COPY install_packages.R /install_packages.R
COPY packages_scan.R /packages_scan.R
COPY rstudio-prefs.json /home/rstudio/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json
COPY .Renviron /home/$USER 
RUN  echo "HOME='/aci/scripts/R.generiek/User.settings/$USER'" >> /home/$USER/.Renviron
RUN cat /home/$USER/.Renviron
 
# Install ODBC and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    cron \
    nano \
    tdsodbc \
    odbc-postgresql \
    libsqliteodbc \
    apt-transport-https \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    unixodbc-dev \
    ## clean up
    && apt-get clean \ 
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ \ 
    && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds
 
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends msodbcsql18 
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
 
## install R-packages
RUN Rscript /install_packages.R
 
# Install depencendcies
RUN apt-get update \
   && apt-get upgrade -y \
   && apt-get install -y \
   # for rJava
   default-jre \
   # for V8
   libv8-dev \
   python3-pip \
   xclip 
 
# Run the R packages scan
RUN Rscript /packages_scan.R


There are multiple issues. You cannot change the user under which a container is running simply by changing the USER variable. Instead you need to create a user inside the container using RUN adduser, and then set the user using the Dockerfile USER directive (not the environment variable or argument). — But this is a lot more effort than necessary. Instead of changing the user, you can mount your host folder into $HOME (i.e. /home/rstudio) inside the container.

thank you! I will try to change the host folder, that sounds more efficient indeed.
